# Can I travel to France with Fiktionsbescheinigung (Fiction Certificate) of Germany

Tags: germany, india, france

I am planning to travel to Germany from India and would want to stay in Paris in between for a week.
I have Fiktionsbescheinigung from the German Government.

[image]

Comment: Your question isn’t entirely clear.  is Is your planned route India > Germany > Paris, or India > Paris > Germany?

Comment: There are three different kinds of Fictional Certificates and the answer depends on which one you have. You might not even be allowed to enter Germany, but practice and law interpretation is disputed and complicated. Nevertheless, since Fictional Certificates are issued preceeding or following a residence permit, your question is probably better fit on Expatriates Stack Exchange.

Comment: The picture you have supplied suggests that you were in Germany when you received your Fiktionsbescheinigung. The question suggests you were in India. Which one is it?

Comment: @Traveller Oops, sorry, I didn't notice the edit. Deleting my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES! but only if the Ficktionsbescheinigung was issued after a `§ 81 Abs. 4  of the AufenthG`

https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326233/

so if yours is

> § 81 Abs. ***3***  of the AufenthG

then no

Comment: I've 81 Abs. 4 but this link does not show If I am permitted to other Schengen country or not

Comment: § 81 Abs. 4 is a continuation of an existing residence permit.

Answer (score 2):

**Under current exceptional circumstances, you need to check relevant COVID regulations as well.**

You will be required to undergo COVID testing in India or France. A mandatory quarantine may be ordered if the result is positive or you present symptoms.

Additionally, you will need to sign a [certificate that you are symptom-free and give reason for your travel to France before you are allowed to board](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage). If your reason indicated is for transit, you may be questioned on why your itinerary to Germany is not as soon as possible.

---

Ordinarily, a Fiktionsbescheinigung is considered to be equivalent to a residence permit under the following circumstances:

> **Fiktionsbescheinigung (Provisional residence document)**
>
> Only if the third box on page 3 is ticked –the residence permit continues to be valid.  Entry  is  allowed  only  in  connection  with  an  expired  residence  permit  or visa.
>
> If the first or second box is ticked, the “Fiktionsbescheinigung” does not entail the right of entry without a visa.
>
> https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_22.pdf

If this applies to you, you can travel within the Schengen area without visa for short stays (90/180 rule) and can enter from whichever Schenge country to transit to the residence country.

Comment: The 3rd box is: § 81 Abs. 4,  continuation of an existing residence permit.